# Label tag asp-for is not displaying

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have this ViewModel class

```
public class ThirdPartyTransfer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Transfer Amount")]
    public decimal TransferAmount { get; set; }

}
```

and in my C# Razor Pages, ThirdPartyTransfer.cshtml

```
   <div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="ThirdPartyTransfer.TransferAmount" />
    <input asp-for="ThirdPartyTransfer.TransferAmount" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="ThirdPartyTransfer.TransferAmount" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

and what is being rendered out is below

```
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="ThirdPartyTransfer_TransferAmount" />
    <input class="form-control" type="text" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Transfer Amount must be a number." data-val-required="The Transfer Amount field is required." id="ThirdPartyTransfer_TransferAmount" name="ThirdPartyTransfer.TransferAmount" value="" />
    <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ThirdPartyTransfer.TransferAmount" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

I wonder why I could see the textbox but not the label.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, Steve, your issue is related to your HTML. A label tag isn't supposed to be self-closing.

Change that to `<label asp-for=""></label>` and you're good to go!

From Microsoft Docs;

**Self-closing Tag Helpers**

Many Tag Helpers can't be used as self-closing tags. Some Tag Helpers are designed to be self-closing tags. Using a Tag Helper that was not designed to be self-closing suppresses the rendered output. Self-closing a Tag Helper results in a self-closing tag in the rendered output. For more information, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring?view=aspnetcore-2.2#self-closing) note in [Authoring Tag Helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring?view=aspnetcore-2.2).